# Is there docs for tensorflow resource_variable?

Tags: tensorflow

I was using tensor_forest, and the trees are being saved as `resouce_variables`. and there is no document about them. it would be really helpful, if there is some docs about how resource is different and similar with tensors

Answer (score 0):

The documentation we have available, as of June 2018, is in [tf.contrib.eager.Variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/Variable), which is an alias for ResourceVariable.